# Losses and/or inefficiencies using a DC/DC voltage regulator?

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, dc-dc-converter

I have a Li-Ion power pack that has either bad 18650 batteries and/or bad charging circuitry. I have 18650s, and I can get a different board on ebay. What I need to do is step down the voltage from the batteries, which are all in series, to 5V USB input.

I can either leave the 18650s in their current arrangement and step down the voltage from 55V to 5V, or I can rearrange the batteries such that I have seven pairs of about 8V in parallel, and step that down to 5V.

Is it more efficient to step 55V down to 5V or 8V down to 5V? I need to get the most power out of the batteries possible. I have room inside the pack for a Raspberry Pi (which is the purpose), but not much else.

If it's better to go 8V to 5V, I might be able to sacrifice some of the pairs for more room in the pack, if the charging circuit won't notice some missing batteries.

Comment: 8 to 5 V given a fixed price for the components. The danger and difficulty lies in rearranging and balance charging your new battery pack.

Comment: More detailed, the lesser losses in 8 to 5 V comes from much less diode-in time in case of asynchronous rectification and in general due to MOSFET die area and price raising with ~voltage^2.2.

Comment: I'd figure out where the problem lies with your existing pack before redesigning it.

Comment: Why would you want to use a power pack with a faulty component. Fix it or get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely due to 1 weak cell in series.  When batteries are overstressed, they fail sooner with fewer than rated charge cycles.  The balanced voltage at the start-of-life becomes accelerated towards end of life as the weakest cell charges up fastest and drains fastest.

Unfortunately the quality of LiPo cells is not only measured in mAh, ESR but the degree of mismatch unless you have an internal active balancer. Passive balancers are ok up to a point because they are designed to a thermal limit which means a certain percentage of the cell charge rate power per cell. e.g. x% of 4Vx3A= 12W so they often rely on balancing only after the CC phase when currents are declining.

> You may want " max power or max current" which are different and not possible to get both as it is parameter dependent unless you do as Mfg specifies.

**Max power** out of a battery uses higher CV charge voltage ( e.g 4.2, 4.3) and lower cutout voltage at lower current rates, which leads to shortest life.

Whereas **Max current and battery life,** uses higher quality balanced batteries with less memory effect and lower ESR and may reduce CV to <=4.1.
good brand: e.g. Enerloop 5th gen

Comment: The more the current you drain from the battery, the less its capacity will be (usually). Good answer, upvoted